# "user_pseudo_id" for data coming from google play console

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play-console

I am aware that installs related data can be found on google play console.
I am using bigquery to analyze the app data.

The two are siloed / separate.

How to check what percentage of installs actually launched the app? Since bigquery does not have installs data. If I integrate bigquery with google play console, will each install be visible with a unique "user_pseudo_id" which I can track the user journey of in bigquery(when did it first launch, what events used etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The term **"user_pseudo_id"** is not directly available in the data coming from Google Play Console. Instead, it is a unique identifier that is typically associated with user data in Google Analytics for Firebase when you use it in your app.

When you integrate your app with Google Analytics for Firebase, you can get access to the ["user_pseudo_id"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid) in the analytics data, and this identifier is used to track user behavior and events within the app. The "user_pseudo_id" is an anonymous identifier that is randomly generated and remains consistent for the same user across different app sessions. It allows you to perform user-level analysis without exposing the actual identity of individual users.

To get user-level data and "user_pseudo_id," you need to integrate your app with Google Analytics for Firebase and set up a BigQuery export as mentioned in my previous response. This way, you can leverage BigQuery to analyze user behavior and track their journey by using the "user_pseudo_id" and other analytics data.